# How to extract city, country, latitude and longitude from google places result

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I am using the following Google Places script to get the location of the user. I get the full address, but I need to parse the result to get city, country.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Google Places Autocomplete textbox using google maps api</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtAutocomplete'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var location = "<b>Address</b>: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>Latitude</b>: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
        location += "<b>Longitude</b>: " + place.geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = location;
    });
}
</script>
<span>Location:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete" style="width: 300px"     placeholder="Enter your address" /><br /><br />
<label id="lblResult" />
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried the below script, but it does not work all the time as in some cases, address format is different.

```
var city = place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '';
        document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = location;
        console.log(city);
```

Comment: Not sure who down voted your question, it seems perfectly reasonable to me. It had me stumped a while back until I figured it out.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a look at `console.log(place);` you'll see something like...

[image]

The returned object contains `address_components`. This is an array which is created from the available data so you can't guarantee what fields it will contain. More details about what is returned can be found in the [description of the Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResponses).

You need to loop through the array and extract out the fields that you need. `city` may not exist but `postal_town` or `locality` might in which case you'll want to use those values instead.

Bear in mind that you may not get any value for `city` or `country` if that data is not available.

There is some [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) on the Google Developers Site which does most of what you need.

Comment: Is there a way to get city and country using some other plugin or method, any other service other than Google..?

Comment: You could use Nominatim which is a search engine built on Open Street Map. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim There are some example lookups on that page. Google and OSM are the two highest profile global options. There are country specific options in the UK for instance we have https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-openspace/api/ but I think that is a paid service. But I'm interested as to why Google is not an option for you?

Comment: Thinking about it further, you could also use an IP lookup to get location. There are a number of services that provide this. See http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup for example. These however are much less likely than Google to return accurate data.

Comment: If you need to do this in a client-side script, Google Places is probably one of the best systems. If you are able to do something at the server end, you could consider using geo-ip lookup on the user's IP address. I've had good results using MaxMind's free databases - they are less detailed than their paid ones, but for city and country level data, they should be sufficient. Have a look here: https://www.maxmind.com/en/open-source-data-and-api-for-ip-geolocation  There are implementations of the lookup code for Rails, Node.js, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), because it provides defense against errors when a property is missing, or the passed-in value is not the expected type.

While I'm sure there's more elegant ways, I've developed this method for plucking certain pieces of information from Google Places information:

ES5 version [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/dzyoamjs/):

```
var address = place.address_components;
var city, state, zip;
address.forEach(function(component) {
  var types = component.types;
  if (types.indexOf('locality') > -1) {
    city = component.long_name;
  }

  if (types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') > -1) {
    state = component.short_name;
  }

  if (types.indexOf('postal_code') > -1) {
    zip = component.long_name;
  }
});

var lat = place.geometry.location.lat;
var lng = place.geometry.location.lng;
```

Utilizing Lodash:

```
var address = _.get(place, 'address_components');
var city, state, zip;
_.forEach(address, function (component) {
    let types = _.get(component, 'types');
    if (_.includes(types, 'locality')) {
        city = _.get(component, 'long_name');
    }

    if (_.includes(types, 'administrative_area_level_1')) {
        state = _.get(component, 'short_name');
    }

    if (_.includes(types, 'postal_code')) {
        zip = _.get(component, 'long_name');
    }
});

var lat = _.get(place, 'geometry.location.lat');
var lng = _.get(place, 'geometry.location.lng');
```